# How to make an element parent of another div forcefully

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've come for 3 problems. I know, javascript can fix it. But, I don't know javascript well. So, I need your help.

(1)I've to make the element "class dropdown" parent div of "div C" forcefully.
for example, This is the structure:

```
<div class="A">
  <ul>
     <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">About</li>
     <li><a href="#">About</li>
     <li><a href="#">About</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="B"></div>
<div class="C"></div>
```

I know, one or 2 lines javascript code make that. But, I don't know the code. So, what's the javascript code for makeing li.dropdown to the parent of "div C"?

(2) How to close a div by onclick option? Like the structure:

```
<a href="#" class="collapse"></a>
<div class="main-nav"></div>
```

By default, main-nav is `display: none` When, anyone click on the collapse link, the main-nav div will be open. And when people click on the collapse link again, main-nav will close again. I can open the main-nav by javascript. But, I can't close it. I've tried by this way:

```
for(var a=0; a<document.getElementsByClassName('collapse').length; a++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('collapse')[a].onclick = function(){
        var mainNav = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('main-nav')[0]
        if(mainNav.style.display = 'none')
            mainNav.style.display = 'block';
        else
            mainNav.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

I think at below lines there is the problem. Please, help me for fixing it.

```
if(mainNav.style.display = 'none')
                mainNav.style.display = 'block';
            else
                mainNav.style.display = 'none';
```

(3) How can I change a background by javascript. Like a div is defined with this:

```
.main-nav li.dropdown a {
    background: url(../images/nav-arrow.png) 70% center no-repeat;  
}
```

I want change the background image when people clink on that. I've tried by way below. But, it won't work :(

```
for(var a=0; a<document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown').length; a++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[a].onclick = function(){
        var innerSubmenu = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('inner-submenu')[0]
        dropdown.backgroundImage = 'url(../images/nav-arrow-hover.png)';
        if(innerSubmenu.style.display = 'none')
            innerSubmenu.style.display = 'block';
        else
            innerSubmenu.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

May be, problem on this line:

```
dropdown.backgroundImage = 'url(../images/nav-arrow-hover.png)';
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'making an element a parent of another element'? A parent-child relationship, in JavaScript implies that one element (the 'child') is contained within the other ('parent'). Are you wanting to re-arrange the DOM (move one element into another) or have a click on one element affect another?

Comment: Do you want to take all divs with class C and put them inside the li tag?

Comment: yes, I want all divs with class C and put them inside the li tag. Basically, class C isn't submenu. But, at one case I've to show class C inside the class dropdown

Comment: re-arrange the DOM (move one element into another) @DavidThomas

Answer (score 0):

Those questions are totally unrelated, I believe you should have posted them as separate questions. Anyway, here are my answers:

(1) - assuming there is a single element of each class

```
document.querySelector('.C').appendChild(document.querySelector('.dropdown'));
```

(2)

```
if(mainNav.style.display != 'block')
        mainNav.style.display = 'block';
    else
        mainNav.style.display = 'none';
```

(3)

```
dropdown.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../images/nav-arrow-hover.png)';
```

Comment: Thanks. (2) is working. At (1) there is not single element of each class. That's why, it hasn't work properly. (3) is also not working

Comment: The key in (1) is `parent.appendChild(parent)`. If you have multiple elements, it's a matter of selecting, looping, then applying that. For (3), consider that the URL is relative to the page, not to your js or css. Try with an absolute url.